# How to display emojis in PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I wanted to make a simple Program like:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):  
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(500, 500, 400, 200)
        self.setWindowTitle('Button')
        button = QPushButton('click me ️'), self)
        button.setGeometry(100, 75, 200, 50)
        button.clicked.connect(self.click)
        self.show()

    def click(self):
        dosomething()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

However, the emoji just shows up as a square.
I read something about that I could change the font to a font that supports emojis.
I also read that the standard font is the system standard font but after changing all different fonts I could change in Gnome Tweaks (in on Ubuntu) to a font that is easily distinguishable, the font of the button remained the same.
I'm so confused.
Do I have to change the Font manually in the Python code by using QtFont?
Or is there any other simple trick to display emojis?

Comment: Try using its unicode number `button = QPushButton('click me \U0001F923', self)`

Comment: @alec Sorry this is not working, and I also tried to set another Font with ```button.setFont(QFont('Liberation Sans', 12))```, but the emoji was still not displayed. :(

Comment: @djnepi That's obviously because the Liberation Sans font doesn't include that particular emoji glyph. You need to find a font that specifically includes all the glyphs that you want to display. Very few standard fonts will include highly specialised glyphs like colour emojis. On my arch-linux system, the ttf-joypixels font includes the one shown in your question - but others like noto-fonts-emoji don't. Personally, I would avoid all the hassle with fonts and just use a QToolButton with an icon.

Comment: @ekhumoro Ok thanks I'll try but when I insert the emoji in LibreOffice and change the font to Liberation Sans its getting displayed. I guess LibreOffice uses something special to display emojis whether the font supports them or not. Thanks.